# How to pass elements of different tags in XML in one line in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

This may be a noob question, but I have looked at several questions/articles about parsing XML files in Python, and the files used as examples never really look like mine, so I'm a bit stuck.
Here's an example of what I have:

```
<item client="client_A" is_known="yes">
 <sales1 id="sales1_name" check="no"></sales1>
 <sales2 id="sales2_name" check="yes"></sales2>
</item>
<item client="client_B" is_known="no">
 <sales1 id="sales1_name" check="yes"></sales1>
 <sales2 id="sales2_name" check="yes"></sales2>
</item>
<item client="client_C" is_known="yes">
 <sales2 id="sales2_name" check="yes"></sales2>
 <sales3 id="sales3_name" check="no"></sales3>
</item>
```

The main part of the file is just a series of item tags, with attributes, and other tags nested in them.
What I would like to do is transform it in a pandas DataFrame in Python, but I would like all of the info inside the item tags to be on line, e.g.:

| client | is_known | sales_id | sales2_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client_A | yes | sales1_name | sales2_name |

Using the pandas and xml.etree.ElementTree libraries, I have been able to build the following code:

```
#DataFrame with the desired columns
df_cols = ['client',
           'is_known',
           'sales1_id',
           'sales2_id'
          ]

#empty list that is filled with the loop
rows = []

#Loop that goes through the tags, look for the attribs and pass them into the rows 
for node in root.iter():
    client = node.attrib.get('client')
    is_known = node.attrib.get('is_known')
    sales1_id = node.attrib.get('id')
    sales2_id = node.attrib.get('id')
    
    rows.append({
        'client': client,
        'is_known': is_known,
        'sales1_id': sales1_id,
        'sales2_id': sales2_id
        })
    
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

But all I got is this:

[image]

So my problem here is double:

1. How can I display all the data on one line?
2. How can I tell my code to find the correct value for attributes that are the same among different tags?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a couple of examples of `<item>` elements in text, not as an image?

Comment: Sure, I just updated it with more examples of item, adding a 3rd salesman. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
items = root.findall('.//item')
rows = []
for item in items:
    row = []
    row.extend([item.attrib['client'],item.attrib['is_known']])
    for sale in item.findall('.//*'):
        row.append(sale.attrib['id'])
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=df_cols)
```

Output:

```
    client  is_known    sales1_id   sales2_id
0   client_A    yes     sales1_name     sales2_name
1   client_B    no  sales1_name     sales2_name
2   client_C    yes     sales2_name     sales3_name
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to tweak it a little bit, in order to have a 3rd column called "sales3_id", so that the name of the salesmen for client C will go in the correct columns, but that's a fantastic improvement compared to where I was before!

Comment: @Nicotops Obviously, the answer only addresses what's in the question (not real life...), but it should indeed be easy to tweak.